# Ruby on Rails 4, Gem Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I have had a lot of difficulty installing Gems into my Rails 4 Apps that I have built. For example, I have recently had issues with these two Gems:

Ckeditor:
https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Twitter Bootstrap 3:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, in the slightest. I include the gems in my Gem file (gem 'ckeditor_rails'), and then I run 'bundle install'. However, whenever I provide my includes in my application.js (example: '//= require ckeditor/init'), my app yells at me and tells me that it cannot resolve the file. When I check why, its because no file was ever downloaded. Even though the gem installed with no errors. I have got to think I am doing something wrong. Any advice?

Comment: what the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Before installing gem, first noted if there is any dependency gem. if the gem having dependency gem means you must install it first. and you may edit in your project/gem file `gem 'ckeditor'` and `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` and then run the server.